# Procedure Or Function SpAddDepartment Has Too Many Arguments Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

**Problem**

I get an error

> Procedure or function spAddDepartment has too many arguments specified

How to solve it?

Details: when inserting data into table `department` using stored procedure `spAddDepartment` using fluent api in ASP.NET MVC 5, I get that error mentioned above.

Table `Departments`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Departments]
(
    [DepartmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL
)
```

Stored procedure `spAddDepartment`:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAddDepartment]
    @DepartmentName    nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Departments 
    VALUES (@DepartmentName, 1) 
END
```

`Department` model class:

```
public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Database context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("spAddDepartment").Parameter(pm => pm.DepartmentName, "DepartmentName")));
}
```

`DepartmentController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(Department depart)
{
    depart.IsActive = true;

    hr.Departments.Add(depart);
    hr.SaveChanges();

    return View(depart);
}
```

Department view:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Department</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: error display on runtime

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `SaveChanges()`, it will make this call to the database (assuming the `DepartmentName` is `Dep1`:

```
exec [dbo].[spAddDepartment] @DepartmentName=N'Dep1',@IsActive=1
```

That is why you are getting the error because your stored procedure only has 1 parameter but EF is looking for a stored procedure with 2 parameters.

You ask why 2 parameters? Because your class has 4 properties: one is virtual so that one is ignored, the `DepartmentID` is identity column so that one will be auto generated and thus not required, the other 2 properties (`DepartmentName` and `IsActive`) are required and therefore it is expecting a stored procedure with 2 parameters as shown above.

**Fix**

To fix the issue, add another parameter to your stored procedure.